# Creating a Table Adapter in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use a datagridview for displaying several different tables data upon a radio click event. My problem is that the table adapter is not showing up but when I check the .xsd file, it say it is there, but in the design it is not and I'm unsure of what to do to get it to show there. Here is my code:

```
private void QBC_CM_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // fill the form with the users on form load
    this.usersTableAdapter.Fill(this.qbc_clothing_ministryDS.users);  
}

private void radioBtnUserReports_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // since user reports was selected
    // bind the datasource to this.usersBindingSource (bound to users table)
    dgvReports.DataSource = this.usersBindingSource;

    // rename the header text visible (so it's not the database column names)
    dgvReports.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
    dgvReports.Columns[1].HeaderText = "First Name";
    dgvReports.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Last Name";
    dgvReports.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Address";
    dgvReports.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Phone";
    dgvReports.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Cell";
    dgvReports.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Email";
}

private void radioBtnClothingReports_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // since the clothing reports was selected
    // bind the datasource to this.qbc_clothing_ministryDataSet1.clothing_reports (clothing reports table)
    this.qbcClothingReportsBindingSource.DataSource = this.qbc_clothing_ministryDataSet1.clothing_reports;

    dgvReports.DataSource = this.qbcClothingReportsBindingSource;

    //  rename the header text visible (so it's not the database column names)
    dgvReports.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
    dgvReports.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Name";
    dgvReports.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Clothing Taken";
    dgvReports.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Month";
    dgvReports.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Year";

    // why is this data from the db not showing up?
}
```

Here are some screenshots that also will help explain (hopefully)

.xsd file: [image]

form design file: [image]

program running - [image]

and finally the data in the database (mssql server) - [image]

I know if I could reference the table adapter, I think I could load the data but it's not showing up (like usersTableAdapter).

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the project tab in Visual Studio (VS) and click the **Add New Data Source...** option. A window will pop-up choose the **Database** option and click [Next>]. Then click **Dataset** and again click [Next>]. This will bring up the data connection settings. Create a **New Connection** by clicking the [New Connection...] button. This will allow you to add a connection. Enter your server name in the server name text box. You can then enter the details on login in the **Log on to server** section of this window. Once you do those things click the [Test Connection] button and you should be all good. If that does not work then make sure you entered all the correct info on this window.

If its all good click [Ok] on that window and then click [Next>], a window will check boxes should appear. Under tables selected all the ones you want to use. Then click [Finish].

Now you should be able to use the table adapters for the data tables in the database, for example:

```
var myTableAdapter = new nameYouGaveDataSetTableAdapters.youTableTableAdapter();
System.Data.DataTable dt = myTableAdapter.GetData();
```

this will load in the data to the data table dt."nameYouGaveDataSetTableAdapters" is default named as yourDataBaseTableAdapters.